# ¿Cómo hago un "if" con múltiples condiciones en Bash?

Tags: bash, condiciones

La sentencia que quiero ejecutar es la siguiente:

si $result es igual a XXX o es igual a XXX o es igual a XXX entonces

Lo tengo así:

```
#valor variable result
result=$(curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --silent -X GET "$pagina")


#Aca en este if quiero preguntar ejecutar esta sentencia: si $Result es igual a o a, entonces

if  echo "$result" || grep -q "301 Moved" || grep -q "404 Page Not Found"];then
  echo "Pagina not found"
  else
  echo "pagina found"
fi
```

Pero algo estoy haciendo mal porque no me ejecuta: devuelve bien los valores.

Comment: Te sería más sencillo utilizar el exit code de la ejecución? https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-returns

Comment: no entiendo como utilizar esos codes, solo quisiera arreglar la consulta que puse arriba, me resultaria mas facil..

Comment: Debes utilizar test para comparar cadenas. En bash se suele utilizar algo tipo `if [ $result -eq "valor1 ] ; then ` . Buscs en el man de test, encontrarás muchos ejemplos

Comment: Para comparar cadenas (en mi experiencia), se usa `==`. `if [ "$pagina" == "404 Page not found" -o "$pagina" == "303 moved" ]; then`. Pero esa implementación no es muy sólida porque si la página da un 404 con otro contenido, no le vas a poder hacer match.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente pon las condiciones de la siguiente forma:

```
if [ condicion1 ] && [ condicion2 ]
```

En tu caso, probablemente puedes usar una expresión algo diferente como:

```
if grep -q "301 Moved" <<< "$result" || grep -q "404 Page Not Found" <<< "$result"; then 
   # echo "si"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas se conoce como [listas de comandos](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html). Más específicamente, te interesan las listas AND y OR. Las listas AND y OR permiten ejecutar comandos condicionalmente dependiendo del [código de salida](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) del comando anterior.

Por ejemplo:

```sh
# Lista AND
# "comando2" se ejecuta si "comando1" tuvo éxito
comando1 && comando2
```

```sh
# Lista OR
# "comando2" se ejecuta si "comando1" falló
comando1 || comando2
```

Puedes insertar este tipo de listas (y cualquier otro tipo de comando, dicho sea de paso) como condicional del comando compuesto `if`:

```sh
if comando1 && comando2; then
    ...
fi
```

Dicho esto, podemos analizar la razón por la que el código de tu ejemplo no funcionó. Si revisamos de cerca la lista OR, vemos que esencialmente se ejecuta lo siguiente (omito los argumentos de los comandos para simplificar):

```sh
echo ... || grep ... || grep ...
```

La lista anterior significa lo siguiente:

1. Ejecuta el comando `echo`.
2. Si falla, ejecuta el primer comando `grep`.
3. Si falla, ejecuta el segundo comando `grep`.

Debido a que el primer comando de la lista tiene éxito, el resto de comandos no se ejecutan. Imagino que creíste que el comando `echo` mandaría su salida a los dos comandos `grep`, como si se tratara de un *pipeline*, y estos harían la comprobación correspondiente, pero esto no es lo que sucede.

La manera correcta sería alguna de las siguientes:

```sh
# Usando "echo"
echo "$result" | grep ... || echo "$result" | grep ...
```

```sh
# Usando una redirección
grep ... <<< "$result" || grep ... <<< "$result"
```

En este caso en específico también es posible usar los comandos `[[ ... ]]` y `case` dado que pueden realizar [reconocimiento de patrones](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) en cadenas de texto:

```sh
[[ "$result" == *"301 Moved"* ]] || [[ "$result" == *"404 Page Not Found"* ]]
```

```sh
# Este ejemplo necesita la opción "extglob" activada (shopt -s extglob)
[[ "$result" == @(*"301 Moved"*|*"404 Page Not Found"*) ]]
```

```sh
case "$result" in
    (*"301 Moved"*|*"404 Page Not Found"*)
        ...
        ;;
esac
```